# Error when Call curlHelperSetOptString from module CCurl - swift -Kitura

Tags: swift, curl, kitura

i use CCurl (https://github.com/IBM-Swift/CCurl.git) in my project (Kitura https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura) then i call func curlHelperSetOptString , compile "swift build" and get an error:

> duplicate symbol _curlHelperSetOptString in:
>   /Users/xxxx/Documents/server/ServerSwift/.build/debug/ServerSwift.build/UploadService.swift.o      /Users/xxxx/Documents/server/ServerSwift/.build/debug/KituraNet.build/ClientRequest.swift.o
>   ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 :0: error:
>   link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   :0: error: build had 1 command failures

code:

```
import CCurl
var handle=curl_easy_init()
if (handle != nil) {
        let url = "http: //example.com/"
        let buffer=url.cString(using: .utf8)
        curlHelperSetOptString(handle, CURLOPT_URL, buffer)
}
```

Help me ,plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably including `CCurl` directly in your `Package.swift` when it's already included in `Kitura-Net/Package.swift`.

With most Swift modules, this wouldn't be a problem, but `CCurl` has to have a *hack* in it because `libCurl` contains mostly [variadic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) and [Swift doesn't import variadic functions from C libraries](https://akrabat.com/wrapping-variadic-functions-for-use-in-swift/).  The *hack* creates static functions in the C header file to create non-variadic version of the `libCurl` functions.  It's those static functions that are being duplicated here (and each module is compiled separately, so you can't `#ifndef` around them because they can't see each other).

Try removing the `CCurl` dependency from your Package.swift file and just depend on the fact that it's being included for you, and hopefully you'll be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it may be because we have defined the CCurl helper functions as extern inline, rather than as static inline. Apparently extern inline causes one of the references to the defined function to become an external name, which can cause problems if it is imported more than once.

We'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

IBM-Swift/CCurl.git 0.2.2 has been tagged. It contains a fix for the problem mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't have multiple entries under Build Phases/Compile Sources. If yes, remove them.

Also you could try cleaning your project or even run `swift package generate-xcodeproj` again.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are importing ccurl which is already imported in the kitura-net package.